# How to convert this VB.net function to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I use this url: http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert code.
The code which needs to be converted to C#:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Function MyRandomNumber() As String
    Dim min As Decimal = 0.01D
    Dim max As Decimal = 9.91D
    Dim decimalPlaces = 3
    Dim multiplier = CDec(Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces))

    Dim range = (max - min) * multiplier
    Dim val = rand.Next(0, CInt(range + 1))
    Return (val / multiplier + min).ToString()

End Function
```

But when I last time did and copy it to my c# solution it throw error.

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and
>   'decimal'

Converted C# code which doest work:

```
private Random rand = new Random();
public string MyRandomNumber()
{
    decimal min = 0.01M;
    decimal max = 9.91M;
    var decimalPlaces = 3;
    var multiplier = System.Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces));

    var range = (max - min) * multiplier;
    var val = rand.Next(0, System.Convert.ToInt32(range + 1));
    return (val / (double)multiplier + min).ToString();
}
```

THE UNDERLINE RED is this line with error:

> (val / (double)multiplier + min)

Comment: Why are you casting a `decimal` to a `double`? Don't do that. Your original code didn't do that.

Comment: @DourHighArch why? I need to generate RANDOM number like this: 0,235 OR 2,205 IN VB.NET CODE it works perfect why wouldnt in C# ??

Comment: Incidentally, the name of the function seems to be wrong, because it returns a string, not a number.

Comment: It is very peculiar to return numeric values as strings; this opens up all kinds of problems with localization, significant digits, and such. If you are printing or displaying these results it should be the printing or display that converts to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct conversion is:

```
return (val / multiplier + min).ToString();
```

Exactly as it is in the VB.Net source. `double` and `decimal` are different types with different precision; do not cast between them unless you are doing something very very strange.

Comment: Exactly - and multiplier and min are both decimal anyway - no need to cast.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas ok i got it and how do I call this function in button1? In vb.net I only put: MyRandomNumber and it worked c# im confused

Comment: @Jana I see no button1 in your question; if you are doing something else ask a new question.